# calculate styleClass on xp:button not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages, ssjs

I want to compute the styleClass property on an xp:button similar to the disabled computation for that button:

```
if (viewScope.get("maskBtnContinue") == true){
    return true;
}
else{
    return false;
}
```

so similar for the styleClass I use:

```
if (viewScope.get("maskBtnContinue") == true){
    return "btn btn-default";
}
else{
    return "btn btn-primary";
}
```

When I perform a partial refresh on the xp:panel that contains the xp:button I notice the disabled property changes for the xp:button when viewScope "maskBtnContinue changes but the styleClass remains having the same value.

Anyone can tell me how I should change the class for the button properly when the viewScope changes?

Answer (score 2):

You have to disable runtime-applied styles on the button.

I did a small test and had the same issue.
After checking 'Disable runtime-applied default styles' on the button, it worked.
Or in source mode: add disableTheme="true" as property for the button.

Comment: Hi Tom, I will take a look at it. Thanks for your help!